# Can't launch JProfiler from Eclipse - NPE in source lookup

Tags: eclipse, jprofiler

I have been using JProfiler 7 in Eclipse for over year, but periodically my Eclipse seems to get into a state where I can no longer run a Profile and I get a NullPointerException from the Eclipse internals.  When running a profile that had previously worked I get the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching TestMain".

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.JavaSourceLookupUtil.getPackageFragmentRoot(JavaSourceLookupUtil.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.JavaSourceLookupUtil.translate(JavaSourceLookupUtil.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.getSourceContainers(JavaRuntime.java:2435)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourcelookup.containers.JavaSourcePathComputer.computeSourceContainers(JavaSourcePathComputer.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.sourcelookup.SourcePathComputer.computeSourceContainers(SourcePathComputer.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.sourcelookup.containers.DefaultSourceContainer.createSourceContainers(DefaultSourceContainer.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.sourcelookup.containers.CompositeSourceContainer.getSourceContainers(CompositeSourceContainer.java:130)
    at com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse.a.f.a(ejt:243)
    at com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse.a.f.j(ejt:230)
    at com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse.a.f.<init>(ejt:70)
    at com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse.a.b.a(ejt:39)
    at com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse.a.b.a(ejt:27)
    at com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse.delegates.LocalJavaDelegate.launch(ejt:18)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

The fact that that it's failing in Source Lookup is interesting, because I have also been having problems in Eclipse generally lately where the IDE is unable to resolve source file locations (even for regular-old Java files that are sitting right there in my project or imported projects), and I have to re-set the source lookup manually (using that "Attach source" button).  So not sure if this is really a JProfiler problem or a basic Eclipse issue.

I was originally working in Eclipse Indigo when I hit this the first time, so I upgraded to Juno and that fixed the problem, but it has now returned and I can't figure out why :)  I've also tried re-doing the JProfiler IDE Integration wizard but that didn't help.

- Rick

Comment: This must be an eclipse problem. Also, we have never seen this before. If you can make a reproducible test case, please send it to support@ej-technologies.com

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get a weird eclipse error like that, I usually just download/reinstall the newest version. If it's something internal to eclipse, I'd advise you to just submit a bug report, reinstall, and carry on being productive. It's annoying to do, but you'll waste less time in the long run.

If you want to submit a helpful bug report to the people that make eclipse possible:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/